# I connected my Google Pixel to my PC using a USB A to USB C cable claiming to support data transfer, but it doesn't show up in Device Manager

Tags: usb, windows, google-pixel

I'm running Windows 10 and Android 9. I can't see the phone in Windows, so I can't transfer files or install apps I'm developing; I'm quite disappointed!

Comment: Is your device set to "Charge only" when plugged in? I'm not sure about Android 9.0 but in older versions you would get a notification saying "USB Charge only", which you could then tap to change the USB mode.

Comment: I'm not getting any notifications at all; all that happens is my phone charges (slowly). I found the USB settings but they're all grayed out. I think my phone's charging port is damaged; the cord is always falling out. Maybe I need to get it repaired?

Comment: Try a new cord. If you still have the issues you are describing you may need to have your USB-C port repaired.